# React: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have spent 2 days trying to understand where is the mistake, any idea?

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Menu from './components/Menu';


function App() {  

    return (
        <Menu></Menu>    
    );
}

export default App;
```

Menu.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import Logout from './Logout';


function Menu() {
    return (
        <button onClick={() => Logout()}>button</button>
    );
}

export default Menu;
```

Logout.js

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
export function Logout() {

    const [user, setUser] = useState();
    const [token, setToken] = useState();

    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    localStorage.removeItem("user");
    setToken();
    setUser();
}

export default Logout;
```

im using the hooks on top of a function (Logout()) so i dont know what happens. maybe because im nesting components? 
because if i move the code from logout.js to menu.js it works but im trying to move the function to other file so i can use it in more components

the error is in:
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

```
  18 | 
  19 | 
> 20 | export function Logout() {
  21 | 
  22 |  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  23 |  const [token, setToken] = useState();
```

Comment: Your logout component didn't return a data. You can transform it to custom hook

Comment: What are you trying to do here `onClick={() => Logout()}`?

Comment: I think `Logout` should be the pure JS function and not the component, try to remove `useState` and it's setter from `Logout` component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663785/invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body-of-a-function-com)

Answer (score 3):

```
function Menu() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState('');
    const [token, setToken] = useState('');

    const logout = () => {
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      localStorage.removeItem("user");
      setToken('');
      setUser('');
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={() => logout()}>button</button>
    );
}
```

Comment: the problem is that Logout is a function (not react component) and you can't define react hooks inside function

Answer (score 2):

Calling `onClick` callback like this:

```
<button onClick={() => Logout()}>button</button>
```

Is equivariant to:

```
const anynomousFunc = () => {
  // Logout()
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [token, setToken] = useState();

  localStorage.removeItem('token');
  localStorage.removeItem('user');
  setToken();
  setUser();
};
```

But notice that `anynomousFunc` **is not a react component**, which leads to:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

```
// Examples of equivalent (but not valid) calls with react components
<div attribute={<Logout/>}>Example</div>
<div attribute={Logout()}>Example</div>
```

To fix this, depending on your application logic, [create a custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) which will return a `function` and use it.