# Errorrrrr: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs

I have developed my own website and have errors using react hook.
The errors are like below.

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
> the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

And here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const ProfileEditing = ({
}) => {

    const user = useSelector(state => state.auth);
    console.log(user);

    return (
        <section className="dashboard">
            <div className='side'>
                <h1 className="large text-primary">Dashboard</h1>
                <p className="lead">
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};

export default ProfileEditing;
```

I try to fix it but doesn't work at all.
Please help me.

Comment: Can you show us where you use `ProfileEditing`? In particular, are you rendering an element (`<ProfileEditing>`) or calling it as a function (`ProfileEditing()`)

Comment: I call this function.
          <Link to="/profileEditing">
                            GO
           </Link>
And I defined /profileEditing in App.js
The point is I use the exactly the same code in other function but it works.

Comment: `I call this function` To use a component you need to render it as an element, not call it as a function. What's the reason you're calling `ProfileEditing()`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't call this function. I link to that function like the code shows.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't need to see the link, just how you render ProfileEditing. The code that you showed in your question should not cause the error you saw, as long as you are rendering `<ProfileEditing>` in a normal way.

Comment: In Dashboard.js I return it.
`code` return (<Link to="/profileEditing">
                            GO
                        </Link>)
When I click GO, it occures error.

Comment: Again, i don't need to see the link. Are you using react-router? If so, the code i'm looking for would look something like `<Route path="/profileEditing" element={</ProfileEditing>}/>`

Comment: Yes, I use react-router and use the code just you write. And I just tried to rendering it but it also throw same error.

Comment: And If I remove useSelector, then everything is Okay.

Comment: I render <ProfileEditing> in App.js
`return (
 <Provider store={store}>
 <Router>
 <Route
 path="profileEditing"
 element={<ProfileEditing />}
 />
 </Routes>
 </Router>
 </Provider>`

Comment: Unable to reproduce. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-m40uec?file=/index.js

Comment: Thank you for your care. I see it works but wonder how it works.
And I still don't know what is difference. And what do you mean "Unable to reproduce"?

Comment: I recreated the code (see the link), and the bug does not exist. That's what "unable to reproduce" means. Maybe you can see what's different from your code, but at the moment, i cannot help, because i cannot see the problem.

Comment: I moved ProfileEditing function to App.js and it works.
I can receive datas from store.
But once I move back to components folder I got error again. It is really hot potato..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed error.
The problem is not because of code but because of `node_modules`.
I removed `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and reinstall it.
And it works now.

Comment: [A question addressing your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971303/react-invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body-of-a-funct) was already created 2 years ago. Please DYOR before asking for anything.

Comment: Maybe questions can be same. But same error occures due to new versions and thus  answers may different. And it is hard to find updated answer in older questions.
In my case, the code was OK. It is just the problem of `node_modules`.
I think it is worth than nothing.
And the `issue` you gave me has no solved mark.
Thanks anyway.