# react hooks invalid call hooks

Tags: react-hooks, redux-form

Hello i'm trying to load a style into my ui stuff but i'm having trouble doing that

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(loginPage)
const classes = useStyles();
const renderTextField = ({
  label,
  input,
  meta: { touched, invalid, error },
  ...custom
}) => (

  <TextField
    label={label}
    placeholder={label}
    variant="outlined"
    InputLabelProps={{
      classes: {
        root: classes.label,
        focused: classes.focusedLabel,
        error: classes.erroredLabel
      }
    }}
    InputProps={{
      classes: {
        root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
        focused: classes.cssFocused,
        notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
      },
      startAdornment: (
        <InputAdornment position="start">
          <PersonSharpIcon style={{ fontSize: 25  , color: 'rgba(20, 176, 12,0.9)' }} />
        </InputAdornment>
      )
    }}
    error={touched && invalid}
    helperText={touched && error}
    {...input}
    {...custom}
  />
)
```

error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
>   of a function component.

Could someone help me how I would solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663785/invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body-of-a-function-com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly as the error message says. You need to move your hook inside the body of your function component.

React considers every function starting with 'use' as a hook. So in your case it's `useStyles()`. React also expects such functions to be called only from inside of the body of function components and only from the root of it (so nesting it inside loops or conditional statements is a big no - you can read about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)). Your function component is `renderTextField`, so as you can see you're calling `useStyles()` OUTSIDE of `renderTextField`'s body.

Structuring it something like this should help:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(loginPage);
const RenderTextField = ({
    label,
    input,
    meta: { touched, invalid, error },
    ...custom
}) => {
    const classes = useStyles(); // <-- Move it here
    return (
        <TextField
            label={label}
            ...
        >
            ...
        </TextField>
    );
}
```

Comment: i got this: React Hook "useStyles" is called in function "renderTextField" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Comment: i think i need withStyle but  
i don't know how i would do that

Comment: My bad. Function component has to start with an uppercase letter ;)

Comment: thanks bro can help me ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59288405/react-textfield-redux-form-component-does-not-allow-writing