# How to properly mitigate invalid hook issues in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Am trying to display my records from **airtable.com** using **reactjs** but it throws error

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
 This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

I have reference solution found here 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663785/invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body-of-a-function-com)

I change the Rec class to function  and then try to export it but still cannot get it to work

**here is the code**

```
import {initializeBlock, useBase, useRecords} from '@airtable/blocks/ui';
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Rec extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            id: ''
        };
    }


myRecords() {
alert('ok');

 const base = useBase();
 const table = base.getTableByNameIfExists('myfirst_table');
 // grab all the records from that table
 const records = useRecords(table);
// render a list of records:
     return (
         <ul>
             {records.map(record => {
                 return <li key={record.id}>{record.id} </li>
             })}
         </ul>
     );


    render() {
        return (
          <div>
             <h2>My Records</h2>

{this.myRecords()}
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Rec;
```

**UPDATED SECTION WITH SOLUTION BY MR. HAGAI**

```
class Rec extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            id: ''
        };
    }


myRecords() {
alert('ok');
 //const base = useBase();
 //const table = base.getTableByNameIfExists('myfirst_table');
 // grab all the records from that table
 //const records = useRecords(table);
// render a list of records:
     return (
         <ul>
             {records.map(record => {
                 return <li key={record.id}>{record.id} </li>
             })}
         </ul>
     );

 }
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
             <h2>Hello welcome to contact page</h2>


 {this.myRecords()}
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default () => {
    const base = useBase();
    const table = base.getTableByNameIfExists('myfirst_table');
    const records = useRecords(table);
    return <Rec base={base} records={records} />
}
//export default Rec;
```

Comment: You can't use hooks in class-based components, only in functional components.  Please show **in your question** how you "change the Rec class to function".  That is crucial to your question.

Comment: Thanks Sir @zero298 for responding. Please any sample implementation or work around

Comment: `function Rec() {
alert('ok');

 const base = useBase();
 const table = base.getTableByNameIfExists('myfirst_table');
 // grab all the records from that table
 const records = useRecords(table);
// render a list of records:
     return (
         <ul>
             {records.map(record => {
                 return <li key={record.id}>{record.id} </li>
             })}
         </ul>
     );

 }
export default Rec;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useBase` and `useRecords` hooks can't be called inside a class component, but there is a little workaround you can do for not re-write code by export arrow function that will pass `base` and `records` as props

```
class Rec extends React.Component{
  ...rest class without useBaes() and useRecords() assiganing... 
}

export default (props) => {
    const base = useBase();
    const table = base.getTableByNameIfExists('myfirst_table');
    const records = useRecords(table);
    return <Rec {...props} base={base} recoreds={records} />
}
```

now `base` available at `this.props.base` and no hook called inside a class component

Comment: Sir @Hagai Harari, thanks for responding. I have implemented your suggesstion  but cannot get it to work. it now displays error `default suspended while rendering, but no fallback UI was specified.

Add a <Suspense fallback=...> component higher in the tree to provide a loading indicator or placeholder to display.
    in _default (created by Context.Consumer)
 `     Please can you see my updated post section titled **UPDATED SECTION WITH SOLUTION BY MR. HAGAI**.  between thanks