# React hooks: Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Trying to create a form to sell and item. Trying to test out printing `itemName` in a `<h1>`, but keep getting the following error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Someone able to shed light on what I'm doing wrong:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

function Selling() {
  const [itemName, setItemName] = useState("");

  function handleChange(event) {
    setItemName(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <h4 className="selling-input-title">What are you selling?</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            class="form-control item"
            id="usr"
            value={itemName} />
        </div>
      </form>
      <h1>{itemName}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you format your code so it's easier to read for us to help? And also remove everything that isn't relevant to the issue / necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your component `Selling` is correct. Your error is likely coming from another part of your code. You may need to share other parts to identify the problem root.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663785/invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body-of-a-function-com)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare like this

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
  setItemName(event.target.value);
  }
```

Comment: still getting the same error. I know it's better practice to use arrow functions though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

export default () => {
  const [itemName, setItemName] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
  setItemName(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <h4 className="selling-input-title">What are you selling?</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text"
            onChange={handleChange}
            class="form-control item"
            id="usr"
            value={itemName} />
        </div>
      </form>
      <h1>{itemName}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```