# Invalid hooks call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic-react

Please have a look at the validate method inside the `elfe-if` condition in the below code. I am unable to call the `useLocation` method of `react-router-dom`. I have seen questions online, one of which is similar to this:  [Invalid hook call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663785/invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body-of-a-function-com). But the solution recommends changing from a class to a function. It might not be the solution for mine because I am using the instance of my class to find the values during my form validation.

```js
export class Reset extends React.Component<IFormProps, IFormState> {
private currentPasswordProvided: boolean;
private passwordValidated: boolean;
private completeValidation: boolean;
private resetParams: ResetPassword;
    
  constructor(props: IFormProps) {
      super(props);

      const errors: IErrors = {};
      const values: IValues = {};
      this.state = {
          errors,
          values
      };
      this.currentPasswordProvided=false;
      this.passwordValidated= false;
      this.completeValidation=false;
      this.resetParams = {
          adminID : '',
          currentPassword: '',
          newPassword: '',
      }
  }

 private setValues = (values: IValues)=>{
     this.setState({values: {...this.state.values, ...values}})
    
 };

 private validate = (fieldName: string, value: string): string => {
     let newError: string = "";
     if(fieldName!=='retypePassword'){
         
        if (
            this.props.fields[fieldName] &&
            this.props.fields[fieldName].validation
        ){
            newError = this.props.fields[fieldName].validation!.rule(
                value,
                fieldName,
                this.props.fields[fieldName].validation!.args
            );
            if(fieldName=='currentPassword' && newError === "")
            {
                this.currentPasswordProvided = true;
            }
            else if(fieldName=='newPassword' && newError === "")
            {
                this.passwordValidated = true;
            }
        }
     }
     else if(fieldName === 'retypePassword'){
        if (
            this.props.fields[fieldName] &&
            this.props.fields[fieldName].ComparePasswordValidation
        ){
            let passwordValues : CompareValue = {
                newPassword: this.state.values.newPassword
            }
            newError = this.props.fields[fieldName].ComparePasswordValidation!.rule(
                value,
                passwordValues,
                this.props.fields[fieldName].ComparePasswordValidation!.args
            );
            if(this.currentPasswordProvided===true&&this.passwordValidated===true&&newError===""){
                const params = useLocation();  //<------ unable to call this  ------------
                const adminID = params.pathname.substr(params.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                this.resetParams = {
                    adminID: adminID,
                    currentPassword: this.state.values.currentPassword,
                    newPassword: this.state.values.newPassword,
                }
                this.completeValidation = true;
            }
            else{
                this.completeValidation = false;
            }
        }
     }
     this.state.errors[fieldName] = newError;
     this.setState({
         errors: { ...this.state.errors, [fieldName]: newError}
     });
     return newError;
 }

  private haveErrors(errors: IErrors) {
    let haveError: boolean = true;
    Object.keys(errors).map((key: string)=> {

        if(errors[key].length > 0){
            haveError = true;
        }
    });
    return haveError;
}

 private async handleSubmit (
    e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>
  ): Promise<void> {
       e.preventDefault();
        try {
            
            console.log(`These are the values----> ${this.state.values}`)
            const resetParams : ResetPassword = {
                adminID: 'adminID',
                currentPassword : this.state.values.currentPassword,
                newPassword: this.state.values.newPassword,
            }
    
            console.log(`These are the params being sent to the API ----> ${JSON.stringify(resetParams)}`)
            /* 
                API call code goes here
            */
          } catch (e) {
            console.log(`Request failed: ${e}`);
            // setShowAlert(true);
          }
     }

    public render() {
        const { submitSuccess, errors } = this.state;
        const context: IFormContext = {
            ...this.state,
            setValues: this.setValues,
            validate: this.validate
        };
        // console.log(`This is the state ----> ${JSON.stringify(this.state.values)}`)
        return (
            <IonPage id="login-registration-page">
            <IonHeader>
              <IonToolbar color="primary">
                <IonTitle>Reset Password</IonTitle>
              </IonToolbar>
            </IonHeader>
            <IonContent>
                <FormContext.Provider value={context}>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-registration-form ion-padding">
                <div className="container">
                    {this.props.render()}
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <IonButton
                           type="submit"
                           //onClick={this.handleSubmit}
                           disabled={!this.completeValidation}
                           expand="block"
                           >Submit</IonButton>
                    </div>
                    {this.completeValidation === false && 
                          !this.haveErrors(errors) && (
                              <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                  Sorry, an unexpected error has occured
                            </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </form>
            </FormContext.Provider>
            </IonContent>
            </IonPage>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) is a [custom react hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) and can only be used inside of a [function component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) i.e. a component that is defined as a javascript function. Your component is a class component.

To access the `location` object provided by your router context in a class component you can use the [`withRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) HOC:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

// A simple component that shows the pathname of the current location
class ShowTheLocation extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props;

    return <div>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>;
  }
}

// Create a new component that is "connected" (to borrow redux
// terminology) to the router.
const ShowTheLocationWithRouter = withRouter(ShowTheLocation);
```

The HOC injects the router context as props `match`, `location` and `history` into your component.

Comment: Hi @trixin, thank you for your answer. To inject the location into ShowTheLocationWithRouter, I would be using `<ShowTheLocationWithRouter location={useLocation()} />`
I don't think that is right, and what does the `match` property do?

Comment: @nawab094 If you want to access the `location` inside of a class based component you need to you the `withRouter` HOC. It's all described in the react-router docs. Did you read it? `useLocation` is a hook and hooks can only be used in function components as I already said. The match property is also described in the docs. Again, please read it.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are not supported in class components. If you can't easily rewrite this as a functional component, one option is to wrap your class component with a functional component and pass `location` in as a prop. It looks like you're only using the `params.pathname` so you could pass that in instead.

Something like this (component names are only a suggestion):

1. Rename `Reset` to `ResetBody`
2. Create a new type for the props by extending.

```js
interface IResetProps extends IFormProps {
    adminID : string;
}
```

3. Create a new component called `Reset` that looks like this:

```js
function Reset(props : IFormProps){
    const params = useLocation();  //<------ unable to call this  ------------
    const adminID = params.pathname.substr(params.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

    return <ResetBody {...props} adminID={adminID} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a class, and you don't want to replace your react class component to function component, you need to use the `withRouter`, in router versions before v6.

**In React-Router-Dom V6**-> this class is not exists any more.

See:
[What happened to withRouter? I need it!](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it)

> This question usually stems from the fact that you're using React class components, which don't support hooks. In React Router v6, we fully embraced hooks and use them to share all the router's internal state. But that doesn't mean you can't use the router. Assuming you can actually use hooks (you're on React 16.8+), you just need a wrapper.

So, you'll need to create your own wrapper, as shown in the docs.

**Here is my implementation**, a little more easy-to-use than doc example:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useLocation, useNavigate, useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

function withRouter(Component) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return <Component {...props} {...{location, navigate, params}} />;
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}

export default withRouter;
```

**Use (when exporting your component):**

```
export default withRouter(Reset);
```

And, in your component, you can use:

```
this.props.location.pathname
this.props.params.paramName
```