# Passing props to dynamically rendered components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a page that is displaying several of my `star` components that each have their own name and a prop called `starType`
I am generating several different of these stars with the following code

```
if (num > 0) {
        return (
          <div className="starWrapper">
            <Star
              name={`${makeid()}`}
            
              starType={`${starList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1)]} ${posList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1)]}`}
            ></Star>
           
           {makeStars((num - 1))}
          </div>
          
        );
```

And this is the star component

```
 <NavLink to={props.name}>
      <h1 className="star-label">{props.name}</h1>
      <div className={``}>
        <div className={`starBall ${props.starType}`}></div>
      </div>
    </NavLink>
```

At the moment I want the user to be able to click on each star and have it lead to a page. I have achieved that with react-router's dynamic routing

```
  <Route
          exact
          path="/:id"
          render={(props) => <GenerateSystem {...props} />}
        />
```

the issue is I want the page that is generated from my `generateSystem` component to have the `starType` prop passed to it by the star component. I am aware of React's one way data flow and I think that might be the issue. How can I pass prop data from an auto generated component to another auto generated component?

My full code is [viewable here](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/planetviewer/tree/main/src). The components I'm talking about are in the `interstellar-view` and `systems` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are passing name through URL params so passing starType using query params is an easy option.

So URL would look like this `www.example.com/123?starType=red-giant`

In your `star.jsx`, make a modification like this

```
<NavLink to={`/${props.name}?starType=${props.starType}`}>
 ...
</NavLink>
```

In your `App.js`, make a modification like this

```
<Switch >
    <Route exact path="/:id"  component={GenerateSystem} />
    <Route exact path="/sol" component={SolSystem} />
    <Route exact path="/" component={Interstellar} />
</Switch>
```

(We do not need to render and pass props since we can use useParams in GenerateSystem.js)

In your `GenerateSystem.js`, make a modification like this

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, useLocation, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}

export const GenerateSystem = (props) => {
    const {name} = useParams();
    const query = useQuery();
    const starType = query.get('starType')

    return(<div className={starType}>System <p>{name}</p></div>)
}
```

Refs:

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams

https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters

EDIT:

You can use Redux-store/Context-API to have a global store, so that name and starType can be stored globally and can be accessed in different components

Comment: I don't 100% understand your answer, but it is working! Thanks for the help and all of the documentation for me to read up on.

Answer (score 0):

**More Use-cases Example ->** for other people that came here:

As in **React-Router-Dom V6**-> there is no `render` method any more,
See [Why does  have an element prop instead of render or component?](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq#why-does-route-have-an-element-prop-instead-of-render-or-component)

> We mentioned this in the migration guide from v5 to v6, but it's worth repeating here.
> In React Router v6 we switched from using v5's  and  APIs to . Why is that?...

So I needed another way of dynamically rendering all routes for the Router, with a pre declared array with all routes:

```
const routingList = [{title: 'Home', search: '/', component: Home, icon: 'fa-home'},{...}]

<Routes>
    {
      routingList.map((routing) => {
       let Child = routing.component;
       return <Route key={routing.search} path={routing.search} element={<Child {...routing.compProps} />} />;
     })
    }
    <Route path="*" element={<Notfound />} />
</Routes>
```

(BTW: if you also need the `useLocation` or the other hooks, and you are using `React Class` and not React functions, see my answer here:

[Component with router props - For: Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72200445/4240256)
)