# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just created a new app,I'm starting to learn react but I'm ready to give up....just before I do want to share my code:

```
index.js:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

APP.js:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Navigation from './component/Navigation';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
<Navigation/>        
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navigation.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Navigation extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="white" >
                <Container>    </NavDropdown>
                    </Nav>
                    <Nav>
                        <Nav.Link href="#deets">More deets</Nav.Link>
                        <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#memes">
                            Dank memes
  </Nav.Link>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>

        </Navbar>
);
    }
}
export default Navigation;
```

Please let me know where is the problem,I also have seen a similar question with no answer...

Comment: The code looks reasonable, but I don't see where any hooks are being used - since that's where the error is, please include the location of the hook call in the question

Comment: please find a function that starts with `use` and post that code here so we can solve it

Comment: @CertainPerformance thats all the code,I only have index.js app.js and in component folder navigation.jsx

Comment: @NishargShah I dont have a use function ,thats all I have

Comment: I think you had two instances of react running at the same time. Surprisingly this did not come to my attention until I tried using react-bootstrap. In my case I installed react via npm while still having the react <script> tag in my master template (obviously resulting in embeding the react code twice).

Comment: @NishargShah let me test,I am installing react boostrap trough npm and will delete the refernce

Comment: `</NavDropdown>` is written **incorrectly**. Should be: `<NavDropdown/>`

Comment: add `<NavDropdown />`

Comment: He also has a </Nav> before the <Nav> element in Navigation.jsx, but this should be a syntax error, not a hook related one.

Comment: @NishargShah I just installed react through npm and it works now ,even though the style is not okay but I am not getting anymore that error...the closing tag is okay

Comment: @NishargShah thanks a lot..aperently I only needed to add boostrap even though I have alredy added in the roor folder

Comment: so should I add that as an answer?

Comment: @NishargShah u'r choice...I'll accept it

Comment: @NishargShah likewise my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had two instances of react running at the same time. Surprisingly this did not come to your attention until you tried using react-bootstrap. In that case, you installed react via npm while still having the react  tag in my master template (obviously resulting in embedding the react code twice).

Answer (score 0):

Like @CertainPerfomance already noted, you aren't using any hooks in the code provided. Nevertheless, if you get the '**Invalid hook call**' error, you're either trying to call a hook from non-functional component(or in other words - a class component) or maybe you're trying to call it in a loop/conditional statement, which breaks the rules for hook usage. Also, you might be importing React twice. Checkout this [official page](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) which should give you some additional information about the specific error.

You will most probably fix your error if you convert your components to functional ones.

EDIT: After your update, also checkout this: [Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663785/invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body-of-a-function-com).