# Error with calling React Hooks inside of Function Component

Tags: reactjs

I don't know why I'm receiving this error after running a test.

`Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

This is how my code looks like

```
  23 |
  24 | const LandingPageNew = () => {
> 25 |   const [displayElement, setDisplayedElement] = useState(1);
     |                                                 ^
  26 |
  27 |   const classes = useStyles();
  28 |   function manageIndicatorColors(element, number) {
```

How you can see I'm using hooks inside **function components**.

Do you have any ideas why this error is occurring?

I've only one React in my project

```
$ npm ls react
   root@ C:\Users\szyma\Desktop\MVPs\pyramid_questionnaire_2
          -- client@1.0.0 -> 
   C:\Users\szyma\Desktop\MVPs\pyramid_questionnaire_2\packages\client
          -- react@17.0.1
```

**Edit------------**

It's pretty simple. `LandingPageNew` is imported to App.js

`import LandingPageNew from "./react/LandingPageNew";`

And then

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className='appComponent'>
        {/* <img src={background} className='top-background' /> */}

        <Route path='/' exact component={LandingPageNew} />
        <Route path='/create-account' component={CreateAccountPage} />
        <Route path='/questionnaire' component={LandingPageNew} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

After using it inside `App.js` everything is by "default"

Comment: You have answer in an `Edit`

Comment: Can you post the full code in the `LadingPageNew` file

Comment: Here you go [link](https://pastebin.pl/view/a63270bd)

Comment: You don't seem to be violating the rules of hooks in that component. So either the problem is somewhere else, or you are mixing up React versions somehow. If you are using `npm link` , this might be the reason https://stackoverflow.com/a/63705440/10648865

Comment: I linked clinet files to correct `node_modules` folder

Comment: So you are using `npm link` ? Have you made sure that the library you are linking points to the react version used in the client? In client `cd node_modules/react && npm link` and in your library `npm link react` and then you npm link the client to the library

Comment: I didn't used npm link before, but I just run the command in client folder which points to correct React depencie. To make sure that those are correctly pointed to each other

Answer (score 0):

Every function component I've written has required properties. It's possible it must accept this as an argument for hooks to recognize it. Try changing

```
const LandingPageNew = () => {
```

To

```
const LandingPageNew = (props) => {
```