# Invalid Hook Call in ReactTS with Route

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I have a `PrivateRoute` component,

```js
interface Props {
    path: string,
    exact: boolean,
    component: React.FC<any>;
}

const PrivateRoute: React.FC<Props> = ({ component, path, exact }) => {
    return (
        <Route
            path={path}
            exact={exact}
        >
            {
                getCookie('name').length !== 0 ? component : <Redirect to="/login" />
            }
        </Route>
    );
}
```

But when I try to use `useState` hook inside a `PrivateRoute`, I get the `invalid hook call` error.

Example,

```js
const [some, setSome] = useState(true);
// Calling this inside a private route will throw an error!
```

How to solve this?

### Edit

This is how `PrivateRoute` is used,

```js
<Switch> // from react-router-dom
   <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
   <PrivateRoute path="/" exact component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

### Edit 2

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usecontext-inside-route-so-example-forked-9dogx?file=/src/SecretPage.tsx)

Comment: for ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663785/invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body-of-a-function-com

Comment: How do you use `PrivateRoute` component in the application?

Comment: @aleksxor can you check now??

Comment: And where do you insert line with `useAuthContext` when it gives you the error?

Comment: @aleksxor I use ```useAuthContext``` inside the ```component``` passed to ```PrivateRoute``` (here ```Home```). ContextProvider wraps around the ```Switch```

Comment: Well, I can't see any problems using hooks inside a Route component. https://codesandbox.io/s/usecontext-inside-route-so-example-qiryj?file=/src/route.tsx

Comment: @aleksxor smh I found the actal error https://codesandbox.io/s/usecontext-inside-route-so-example-forked-9dogx?file=/src/SecretPage.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works now.

```
export const PrivateRoute: React.FC<{
  component: React.FC<any>;
  path: string;
  exact: boolean;
}> = ({ component, path, exact }) => {
  const auth = useAuthProvider();

  return auth.isAuth ?  <Route path={path} exact={exact} component={component}/> : <Redirect to="/" />
};
```

Comment: Yup, I had to remove ```Redirect``` from ```Route```