# Promise Rejection Id: 0 SQLite-React Native

Tags: react-native, sqlite, mobile

I am having a problem retrieving data from or writing to my database. The initialization of the table is successful but if I put any other function I get the following warning and the code doesn't work

```
    export const getDataFromDB = async () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  try {
    const db = await getDB();
    await db.transaction(async tx => {
      await tx.executeSql(
        'SELECT UserName, Password, RememberMe, MapView, DrawEdits, NetworkIP, Port, Auth FROM UsersInformation',
        [],
        (tx, results) => {
          console.log('Database readed');
          var len = results.rows.length;
          if (len > 0) {
            let item = results.rows.item(0);
            dispatch(setUsername(item.UserName));
            dispatch(setPassword(item.Password));
            dispatch(setRememberMe(item.RememberMe));

            dispatch(setMapView(item.MapView));

            dispatch(drawEdits(item.DrawEdits));

            dispatch(networkIp(item.NetworkIP));
            dispatch(networkPort(item.Port));
            dispatch(networkAuth(item.Auth));
          }
        },
      );
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

The error is the following

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 3): Error: Invalid hook
> call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function
> component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem. Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be
>    called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen
>    for one of the following reasons:
> 4. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 5. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 6. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug
>    and fix this problem.

Comment: One of those functions, probably getDb, is a hook, and it's being called outside the body of a functional component. If you search for the error you should find a wealth of information on this topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663785/invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body-of-a-function-com)

Comment: @Abe No, I wish it did, but it didn't solve my problem. I will keep my eyes open for a solution.

Comment: It's useDispatch. You have to move useDispatch out of the body of the function and into the body of the function component.

Comment: Thanks @Abe that was the error. I have been able to solve the problem.