# How to add local package as npm dependency in a "production" way?

Tags: npm

I'm creating a npm package `my-package`, and it has `example` folder with example app, which is a separate project with package.json.

I want `example` app to have a dependency on `my-package` so that it is installed in "production" way - to `example/node_modules/my-package` with only files that are in `package.json` included `files` list, not a symlink with all files as `npm link` does, that causes various errors like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63705440/1768179).

I don't want to add symlink to `dist` folder, because it is not a "production" way, and later when the package is added as dependency through npm, there could be problems that I could not catch with such hacks.

I don't have it published to npm or public repo - it is still in development, and that should not be a problem.

Also, it would be great that this "setting" is saved in git repo, without a need of running any additional commands, so that `example` could be run easily after installing the repo.

Comment: Why can't you publish it? Maybe something like this will help when having mulitple NPM modules in same repo: https://lerna.js.org/

Comment: Because it is still in development.

Comment: Then you should use `npm link`.

Comment: @htor I told in the question why `npm link` doesn't work in my case.

Comment: You can install from the file `npm pack` creates, which is exactly what would be published.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, that seems to be the closest thing I'm searching for. Don't you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The best way of I could find was suggested by @jonrsharpe in comments to the question. It is based on using `npm pack`.

But don't use `yarn`, it has [bug](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6811) with adding tarball deps.

### Old answer:

The best way of I could find was suggested by @jonrsharpe in comments to the question. It is based on using `npm pack`.

In my case with `yarn`:

```bash
# create a tarball
yarn pack -f package.tgz

# add it as dependency
(cd example && yarn add ../package.tgz)
```

Final script to run example app that works on clean repo install:

```json
"example": "tsc && yarn pack -f package.tgz && (cd example && yarn && yarn start)"
```